# How to show Horizontal RecyclerView first 10 items and then swipe to show another 10 items in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Vertical recyclerView with Horizontal recyclerView.Currently i am showing 10 elements in each section (Horizontal recyclerView).. If more than 10 elements i have to first 10 elements then i have to swipe show another 10 elements.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use pagination with itemcount 1 and in each item take first 10 elements

Comment: Hi Shanmugapriyan M, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Group set of 10 items into single `recycler` item view and repeat that `item` using Horizontal `RecyclerView` as in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to show just 10 items at first and swipe to show more items, The better way is to let your recyclerview's width adaptives 10 items total width, so you can custom a LayoutManager for your horizontal recyclerview, and implement it's `onMeasure` method to set the width of the recyclerview.

```

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec,int heightSpec) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);
    measureChild(view, widthSpec, heightSpec);
    //int recyclerViewW = ...;
    //int recyclerViewH = ...;
    //setMeasuredDimension(recyclerViewW, recyclerViewH);
}
```

```

By the way, if the items you want to show is not fixed in size, this way is not eligible.